# Show name based on ID

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

If I have names of locations along with location id's in the same table, how can I display the location name based on the location id?  The location id will never change, but the name might, so by using the value of the id instead of the name will keep all records available.  However, I want the name to be shown and not the id.

Right now I have:

```
select loc_name
from location
where loc_id = loc_name
```

but there's nothing in the output.

Comment: `loc_id` would (hopefully) never equal `loc_name`.  If you're wanting to select the name based on the id, you need to pass in the id you're looking for.  Like: `Select loc_name from location where loc_id = 1`

Comment: `where loc_id=(SELECT loc_id from location where loc_name='someName')`

Comment: @Mihai that is really just a `SELECT loc_name FROM location WHERE loc_name = loc_name`, all dressed up. Why would 'someName' be the variable when trying to select the name from the database?

Comment: Well is useful to understand subqueries but you are right @J-Dizzle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loc_ID is presumably an integer, and Loc_Name is presumably VarChar.  Those 2 fields will never equal, so asking for a dataset where they equal each other will not give you any output.

Instead, you want something like:

```
SELECT 
   loc_name 
FROM location 
WHERE loc_id = YourLocID
```

Where YourLocID above is the value of Loc_ID for the Loc_Name you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifiy the ID you want to see the location for, i.e.:

```
select loc_name from location where loc_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT loc_name FROM location WHERE loc_id = XX

You give XX as the ID, it returns the name